# Xcode IOS Printing ePos SDK Image and Text Together

Tags: ios, xcode, image, text, printing

I am having a problem when trying to print a line of text followed by an image with xcode and ePos.

Printing just text or image works great. But getting them together on one sheet of paper is not working.

It just prints whatever is first and stop. Whether the text is first or the image.

here is my code below.

please help.

My functions contains....

```
PrinterU *pj = [[PrinterU alloc] init];
        EposB *builder = [pj getNewEposB];
        EposP *printer = [pj getNewEposP];
        [pj setPrintStyle:PRINTSTYLE_BODY2 eposBuilder:builder];
        [pj loadTextLine:@"print to tm-p60II \n" eposBuilder:builder];
        [pj loadTextLine:@"DONE BY tester" eposBuilder:builder];
        NSLog(@"%@", signature);
        UIImage*image = [UIImage imageWithData:signature];
        [pj addImage:image X:0 Y:0 Width:300 Height:300 Color:(EPOS_OC_PARAM_DEFAULT) eposBuilder:builder];
        [pj print:builder eposPrint:printer ];
        [pj closePrinterConnection];
```

Comment: Not a single reply... sad

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the printer sdk cannot stretch the images. Fixed it by passing the resolution.